# how to start an animation on the end of another animation?

Tags: animation, svg, fade, smil

I am trying to have a dot fade from white to red and then from white to red.

This is what I have thus far:

```
<circle id="test" fill="#ED1C24" cx="96.881" cy="91.953" r="26.485"/>
<animate id="testies" attributeName="fill" from="#ED1C24" 
to="#fff" xlink:href="#test" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
<animate attributeName="fill" from="" to="#ED1C24"
xlink:href="#test" begin="" onrepeat=" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
```

I want the second animation to begin when the first one ends, I know this is possible, I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using your example, here's how:

```
<circle id="test" fill="#ED1C24" cx="96.881" cy="91.953" r="26.485"/>
<animate id="testies" attributeName="fill" from="#ED1C24" to="#fff"
  xlink:href="#test" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />  
<animate attributeName="fill" from="" to="#ED1C24" xlink:href="#test"
  begin="testies.end" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
```

or as an equivalent alternative without the `xlink:href` syntax:

```
<circle id="test" fill="#ED1C24" cx="96.881" cy="91.953" r="26.485">
  <animate id="testies" attributeName="fill" from="#ED1C24" to="#fff"
    dur="2s" fill="freeze" />  
  <animate attributeName="fill" from="" to="#ED1C24"
    begin="testies.end" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
</circle>
```

So, basically just add the id of the element you want to trigger the other animation from and add a ".end" suffix. You can also specify ".begin" to trigger on the beginning of an animation, or add a time offset, e.g `begin="someId.end+2s"`.

It's also possible to use events to trigger animations, the syntax is similar: id followed by a dot and then the name of the event and optionally a time offset. See the list of events that are required in SVG 1.1 [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#SVGEvents) (the leftmost column labeled "Event name" is what applies here).

If you're not scared of specifications see the [full syntax of the begin attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#BeginValueListSyntax) for all the details.

Comment: This currently does not work in Chrome (34). EDIT: My mistake, is working fine.

Comment: how to use onrepeat attribute? can you explain it with example

Comment: @RiteshDhuri in this example the onrepeat attribute doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: is it possible to replicate this behavior with javascript ?